# Chrome App get CRASH if trying to download Video more than 100MB

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, google-chrome-app, arraybuffer

Created a Chrome App that download and Play video.

But When i try to download Video of Size 800MB , the App get crashed. But if try to download video file <=50MB  it works fine.

Also, m using XMLHttpRequest to get the URL of the video file. For video file of 800MB the video reside over my Local Host.

**My question -**
Is storing video on localhost and then making a GET call for downloading that video making my app crash or something else??
M new to dis, so Plz guide me.

Code snippet:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 var url="http://localhost/videos/Public%20Art%20Fund%20Talks%20at%20The%20New%20School-%20Allora%20&%20Calzadilla-SD.mp4";

 xhr.open('GET', url, true);

 xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  xhr.onload = function(e) {
   // encryption and decryption code
  };
  xhr.send();
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Could you please show some code? And where you storing the video? Or is it crushing during download?

Comment: It is crashing during download before onload function call

Comment: A reason for not using `<video>`  element ?

Comment: No that's not the reason, and i have use <video> element but only for playing.
But the app crash during download.

Comment: no I meant why do you download the video through xhr if you then will redownload it in the `<video>` element?

Comment: **use case for chrome App**
1) Video URL , Download that video and save it in encrypted form.
3) For playing, first decrypt it and then play it using video element.User can only play those video (offline mode ) which are already downloaded.